# Create folder before upload in express js

Tags: node.js, express

How can I create a folder (if the folder does not exist yet) before the image will be uploaded? I always get error `ENOENT`.

When I try this code:

```
module.exports = function(router){

    router.post('/result', directory.tmp, uploader.single, function(req,res){ 
           //some data manipulation here
    });
}
```

`//directory.js`

```
module.exports.tmp = function(req, res, next){
        mkdirp('./tmp/' + moment().format('MM-DD-YY') + '/' + moment().format('HH'), function (err) {
            if (err) console.error(err)
            console.log("==================================");
            console.log("tmp folder created");
            console.log("==================================");
        });
        next();
    };
```

Though I used `directory.tmp` first so it will create a folder if it is not existing, I think `uploader.single` is executed first that is why I got that error. After receiving the error, then that's the time my app created the folder. So in other words, the file uploaded was not saved. How to fix this so it will create the folder first, then upload the file. Btw, I am using `mkdirp` and `multer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do the `next();` inside the callback of mkdirp.

Because like you did, why it creates the folder it calls next and goes further and the folder is not yet created. This is why you should wait for folder creation first.

```
module.exports.tmp = function(req, res, next){
    mkdirp('./tmp/' + moment().format('MM-DD-YY') + '/' + moment().format('HH'), function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
        console.log("==================================");
        console.log("tmp folder created");
        console.log("==================================");
        next();
    });
};
```

Comment: Cool, I hope that with the explanation you understood why it was not working before